# How to assign a texture to a material through code in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
     root_level1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.EnableKeyword ("_NORMALMAP");
     Texture tex = Resources.Load("book-cover-1-glitched-23-11-2020-8-35-56-pm") as Texture;
     root_level1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry. Texture is not showing on object when i run.

Answer (score 0):

1. To change material texture in runtime you should change it by accessing shader properties. First of all you gonna check these properties in shader code or shader properties in unity inspector. If you want to check shader code, your goal is "properties" block:

[image]

Or you can select shader in Unity Editor and check Inspector Window:
[image]

2. So to change Base RGB Texture we should change property "_MainTex" and to change Color we have to change property "_Color".

I your example its gonna be like this:

```
root_level1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_MainTex", tex);
```

Comment: thx for the detailed answer. I have used the above code and its still not showing the texture when i run.

Comment: i should also add that the object im trying to change the texture of is also generated at runtime.